# Maximum number of roots

Tags: calculus, roots

> For non-zero $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and for $α_1,α_2,\dots,α_n$ such that $α_i\ne α_j$ for $i\ne j$, show that the equation $$a_1e^{α_1x}+a_2e^{α_2x}+\dots+a_ne^{α_nx}=0$$ has at most $n-1$ real roots.

[The original image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkXZV.png)

I just don't have a clue how to start.

I tried with Rolle's, and I tried differentiation...but no avail

Comment: Where is the exercise from?

Comment: @KonKan A pdf from net... I don't remember where from....

Comment: I am trying to understand the context here: i think that using rolle you are getting that there is at most 1 root.

Comment: @KonKan Yes.... That is where I am stuck

Comment: Of course, "at most one" is stronger than "at most n-1" for $n>1$ ;)

Comment: @KonKan The main problem is.... Rolle shows "at least " not "at most"

Comment: Rolle shows that there is at least one root of the derivative between two successive roots of the function and that there is at most one root of the function between two successive roots of the derivative.

Comment: And since the derivative is always positive then there can not be a second root of the function.

Comment: @KonKan you can never ensure derivative is positive..... a1, a2,... are not given to be positive or negative

Comment: But $f'(x)=a_1^2e^{a_1x}+...+a_n^2e^{a_nx}>0$. Am i missing something ?

Comment: (if you set $f(x)$ the lhs of your equation)

Comment: @KonKan yes.. One is ai and other is (alpha) i

Comment: aahhh ok! now i got it! sorry i did not read the OP carefully enough.

Comment: Does complex analysis help? Please see!!

Comment: In a modified form, Descartes rule of signs also applies. If you sort the exponent factors $\alpha_i$ in increasing order, then the number of sign variations in the sequence $a_i$ gives an upper bound on the number of real roots. Approximate the $\alpha_i$ by rationals with a common denominator $N$ and you can apply Descartes directly to the close-by polynomial in $u=e^{x/N}$.

Comment: @LutzL Can you explain it a bit more? This sounds like a interesting method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that $a_1e^{\alpha_1 x}+\ldots +a_ne^{\alpha_n x}= 0 \iff 
1 + \frac{a_2}{a_1}e^{(\alpha_2-\alpha_1) x}+\ldots +\frac{a_n}{a_1}e^{(\alpha_n-\alpha_1) x}=0$.
Rolle along with induction should do the trick

Comment: Can you please suggest how? I am totally clueless.

Comment: Let $f(x)=1 + \frac{a_2}{a_1}e^{(\alpha_2-\alpha_1) x}+\ldots +\frac{a_n}{a_1}e^{(\alpha_n-\alpha_1) x}$. Compute $f'$ and note, that it is of the form in your exercise. So by induction $f'$ hat at most n-2 zeros